# AngularJS factory issue

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

In order to make use of Angular JS I tried to use Factory for my data stack...

Now, It does not work. I have just put a simple json data to be returned by factory, and then

the script has stopped working. It is the most basic example of angularjs as it uses json to

repeat and iterate through.

Here is all angularjs that I have written:

```
var Item = angular.module("Item", ['ngRoute']);

Item.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/add", {
            controller : "ItemController",
            templateUrl : "index.html"
        })
        .when("/edit", {
            controller : "ItemController",
            templateUrl : "index.html"
        });
});

Item.factory("ItemsFactory", function(){

    var items = [
        { name : "Washing Powder",
        price : "2000",
        balance : 14
        },

        { name : "Shampoo",
          price : "8500",
          balance : 03
        },

        { name : "Soap",
          price : "1850",
          balance : 27
        }
    ];

    var factory = {};

    factory.getItems() = function(){
        return items;
    };

    factory.postItems() = function(){
        // POST items
    };

    return factory;

});


Item.controller("ItemController", function($scope, ItemsFactory){
    $scope.items = ItemsFactory.getItems();

    init();

    function init()
    {
        $scope.items = ItemsFactory.getItems();
    }


    $scope.AddNewItem = function(){
        $scope.items.push({
            name : $scope.NewItem.name,
            price : $scope.NewItem.price
        });
    };
});
```

And here is the HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <title>Practicing AngularJS Framework...!</title>
    <script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ngroute.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="Item">
        <div data-ng-controller="ItemController">
            <div data-ng-repeat="each in items">
                <p>Item {{ each.name }} costs {{ each.price }}.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" data-ng-model="NewItem.name" />
                <input type="text" data-ng-model="NewItem.price" />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Add Item" data-ng-click="AddNewItem()" />
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It does not load of the json content to repeat them instantly...Nothing happens..

Comment: try chage `input type="submit"` to `input type="button"` or change `data-ng-click` to `data-ng-submit`

Comment: The problem is not clicking event. Read the question, the data returned by (if any is returned) factory is not iterated through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to use some thing like this to return value in service :

```
Item.factory("ItemsFactory", function(){

 var items = [
    { name : "Washing Powder",
    price : "2000",
    balance : 14
    },

    { name : "Shampoo",
      price : "8500",
      balance : 03
    },

    { name : "Soap",
      price : "1850",
      balance : 27
    }
];

return {
   getItems: function(){
    return items;
   },

postItems:function(){

}
});
```

also it think :

```
 factory.getItems() = function(){}
```

is wrong and the correct is :

```
 factory.getItems = function(){}
```

Comment: you last edit did the trick. However before you mentioned I solved it myself, but for future visitors I accept yours as the answer. Thanks for answering